# Is there any open source implementation of the SBEED learning algorithm?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, function-approximation, resource-request

Are there are any openly available implementations of the [SBEED: Convergent Reinforcement Learning with Nonlinear Function Approximation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.10285.pdf) paper?